# How to Add Custom Validation on Magento 2 Admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, validation, core-config-data, savedata

I have created some fields in Magento 2 Admin I want to add some custom validation in Admin Area.

[image]

If I add 200 in Product Cost Column in first row then I want to add 201 in next row if i add value less than 200 then i want to show like ( Please enter greater than value of 200 ) error on saving like it shows on required.

Comment: i think you can use this line in your system.xml ‘validate-zero-or-greater’ => ‘Validate a number should be either 0 or greater in this field’ for more details follow this link https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento2-system-configuration-validation-html.html

Comment: Thanks for the response i will check this out will you please help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319776/how-to-save-custom-created-field-on-checkout-pagefor-guest-user-in-magento-2 @Chikku