# How to get controller path for $postUrl for reading CSV in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, csv, file-upload

I have created custom button in Admin Menu for import CSV and created a controller with below path

```
app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/Controller/Adminhtml/SampleTwo/Index.php
```

Used this in my phtml file with function name

```
<?php $postUrl = 'AdminSample/sampleTwo/index/import'; ?>
```

Is that correct path to use in phtml file.

But in my case it's just refresh the page not die that.

My Controller File

```
<?php
namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Adminhtml\SampleTwo;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface; // Needed to retrieve config values

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
 protected $resultPageFactory;
 protected $csvProcessor;
/**
 * @var scopeConfig
 * Needed to retrieve config values
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig // Needed to retrieve config values
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig; // Needed to retrieve config values
}

/**
* Index Action*
* @return void
*/
public function execute()
{
    
    if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) {

         throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));

     }

     $importProductRawData = $this->csvProcessor->getData($file['tmp_name']);


     foreach($importProductRawData as $rowIndex => $dataRow) {

         \Zend_Debug::dump($dataRow);

     }

     die();
}
}
```

Use that link to refer these https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-read-a-csv-file-convert-it-into-an-array-in-magento-2.html

Comment: First confirm your controller is called or not without that custom code.

Comment: On calling controller it shows 302 Found @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Thanks for the response will you please help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319776/ho-to-save-custom-created-field-on-checkout-pagefor-guest-user-in-magento-2 question @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Confirm that you create routes.xml admin side as well.